# How do I add a ModSecurity rule to block certain http requests?

Tags: nginx, firewall, mod-security, web-application-firewall, mod-security2

I want to create a rule that blocks all http requests (get,post,put, literally all of them) and only allow certain ones that I specify. Specifically, Get, Put and Post. I am running ModSecurity V3.

If there is a rule that can do something like this, if someone wouldn't mind sharing the syntax, I would greatly appreciate it.

Note: Currently I am getting a 403 (Forbidden) response when I attempt to request for a POST/PUT. Not sure why this is.

Thanks!

Comment: `limit_except` is the way to block location request by HTTP method in nginx: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#limit_except

Answer (score 0):

Using ModSecurity, try this rule (last 2 lines are optional):

```
SecRule REQUEST_METHOD "!@within GET POST PUT" \
    "id:20,\
    phase:1,\
    deny,\
    msg:'Method is not allowed by policy',\
    logdata:'%{MATCHED_VAR}'"
```